# Continuous tense for "sitting"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, tense

> She was sitting when I saw her at the bus stop yesterday.
>
> Sie ___, als ich sie gestern an der Bushaltestelle gesehen habe.

Was wäre die beste Übersetzung von dem Teil "was sitting"? In den Antworten zu [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2906/are-sentences-such-as-wir-waren-essen-grammatically-correct) sieht man die Konstruktionen "Wir sind am Essen" und "Wir sind beim Essen", aber das Verb "sitzen" ist passiver als "essen", also ich weiß nicht ob die Konstruktionen hier funktionieren. Oder sollte man die typischen Formen "saß" oder "hat gesessen" verwenden?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: entweder wir antworten oder wir schließen als off topic, aber ein Antwortkommentar ist immer unerwünscht. Wenn Du anderer Meinung bist, hier geht's weiter: https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1305/please-do-not-answer-proof-reading-or-translation-requests

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you say "I was driving when it happened." seeing as German has no Progressive Tense?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20553/how-do-you-say-i-was-driving-when-it-happened-seeing-as-german-has-no-progres)

Comment: I just edited the question. Please let me know if it still doesn't satisfy the standards of the site (and if so, why).

Comment: @guidot Looking at the answers in your linked question (Ich war gerade unterwegs, Ich saß gerade am Steuer, Ich war mit dem Auto unterwegs), I'm not sure they can be easily adapted here. Also I feel ""Ich war grad am fahren" might not apply well to "sitzen" as sitting is more passive.

Comment: @boaten: Nur der Verlaufsform-Aspekt ist nicht off-topic. Mehr Kontext wäre für eine gute Übersetzung hilfreich. *Bei unserem ersten Treffen saß sie gerade deshalb überraschte mich ihre Körpergröße von 1,80 m* oder einfach *Ich sah sie auf der Bank sitzen*....

Comment: @guidot Danke, ich habe nochmal editiert und mehr Kontext gegeben.

Comment: @boaten: danke :)

Comment: *Sie war am sitten been* ist korrekt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*She was sitting when I saw her at the bus stop yesterday.*

> Sie **saß gerade**, als ich sie gestern an der Bushaltestelle gesehen habe.
>
> Sie **war am Sitzen**, als ich sie gestern an der Bushaltestelle gesehen habe.

Die erste Variante klingt viel besser, du wirst aber auch die zweite häufig hören.